# react native - How to use React Hooks in array of tuples?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, tuples

I am trying to make FlatList which reads data from const "values" and renders a list of checkboxes. For the checkbox I use Checkbox.Android from react-native-paper.

Const "values" contain following data:

```
const values = [
{
  name: 'Checkbox 1',
  [check, setCheck]: React.useState(false),      
},
{
  name: 'Checkbox 2',
  [check, setCheck]: React.useState(false), 
},
];
```

React Hook works when I use `const [check, setCheck] = React.useState(false);` , but how to place it inside of "values"?

I am getting error:

```
 Unexpected token, expected "]" 
  123 |     {
  124 |       name: 'Checkbox 1',
> 125 |       [check, setCheck]: React.useState(false),
  |                 ^
  126 |     },
  127 |     {]
```

Sorry, I'm new with this and I couldn't find any complex examples like this case.
Or is this not possible https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions

Comment: This is pretty much not possible. You should use hooks only inside the React functional components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats not possible according to rule of hooks.
but you can do it like this.

```js
//your checkbox state
const [checkbox,setcheckbox] = useState([
{
  name: 'Checkbox 1',
  checked:false,      
},
{
  name: 'Checkbox 2',
  checked:false, 
},
]);
```

and then loop the data or use flatlist

```js
<Flatlist
    data={checkbox}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>{
        return (
            <Pressable onPress={()=>{
            let newcheckbox = checkbox;
            newcheckbox[index].checked = !checkbox[index].checked;
            setcheckbox(newcheckbox)
            }}>
            <Text style={{color:item?.checked ? 'green':'red'}}>
             {`${item?.checked ? 'Checked':'UnCheked'} (click me to change)`}
            <Text/>
            </Pressable>
        );
    }}

/>
```